# why are "least square estimators" in fact "estimators"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I'm trying to reconcile the notion of a "least square estimator" with the definition of an estimator I have in my head.

An estimator for me assumes a set $\Omega$ and a family of probability measures $$\{\mu_\theta: \theta \in \Theta\}$$ on $\Omega$, and a function on the index set $g:\Theta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. An unbiased estimator for $g$ is then a function $\tilde{g}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\int_\Omega \tilde{g} \, d\mu_\theta = g(\theta)$$ for all $\theta\in\Theta$.

A "least squares estimator" on the other hand assumes we have some uncorrelated random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n: \mathscr{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on a space $\mathscr{X}$ (I think with a fixed probability measure?) with common variance and expectations $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n$ assumed to lie in some linear subspace $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (as something varies? what specifically i don't know.  Maybe varies with a family of probability measures on $\mathscr{X}$?).  Then given an "observation" $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we "estimate"  $(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n)$ by just projecting $x$ to the subspace $V$ obtaining say $x'$. Then given any linear $L: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $L(x')$ is supposed to be an estimator for $L(X_1,...,X_n)$.
(I hope that's a fair treatment. I've tried to simplify it by not including the matrix $A$ which parametrizes subspace $V$)

Now my question is how should I define $\Omega$ and $\Theta$ and $\mu_\theta$ and $g$ and $\tilde{g}$ to show that the latter is an instance of the former?  I'd be inclined to just make $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu_\theta$ some kind of product measure if the $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ were independent, but they are only assumed uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

One simple sort of least-squares estimator often considered is as follows. You have
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c} Y_1 \\ \vdots \\ Y_n \end{array}\right] = Y \sim \operatorname N_n(X\theta, \sigma^2 I_n) = \operatorname N\left( \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 & x_1 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_n \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{c} \theta_0 \\ \theta_1 \end{array} \right], \sigma^2 \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 1 \\ & 1 \\ & & \ddots \\ & & & 1  \end{array} \right] \right) \tag 1
$$
where $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are known non-random numbers and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are observed, so that the observed data are $(x_i,Y_i),\,\, i=1,\ldots,n.$ The thing to be estimated is $\theta.$ The variance $\sigma^2$ will also be estimated, but not by least squares. The least-squares estimate of $\theta$ is
$$
\widehat\theta = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y.
$$
In this case, $\Theta=\mathbb R^2$ and $\Omega$ can be taken to be $\mathbb R^n$ with the measure given on line $(1)$ above.

If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are only assumed uncorrelated and not independent, then you're still dealing with a measure on a product space, albeit not a product measure.

Comment: Thanks Michael,  could you tell me if this sounds right: in general $\Theta$ is a set of $n$-tuples of real-valued random vectors $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ with each $Y_i$ defined on a common probability space $(\mathscr{X}, \nu)$ and $\mu_{(Y_1,...,Y_n)}$ is just the pushforward $(Y_1,...,Y_n)_\ast(\nu)$?

Comment: No. $\Theta$ in this case is the set of possible values of $[\theta_0,\theta_1]^T.$ It's $\mathbb R^2. \qquad$

Comment: Ok so in line (1) the measure is just a product of some normal measures, correct?

Comment: But in general (in the Gauss-Markov Theorem, e.g.), the $X_i$'s are not assumed normal or independent, so in that case would it make sense to let elements of $\Theta$ be whatever random vector (with common variance and with vector of expectations lying in a subspace) induces the measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$? And then $g(Y_1,...,Y_n) = L(E(Y_1),...,E(Y_n))$?

Comment: @Timkinsella : Members of $\Theta$ are not treated as random in this context. And regardless of whether one uses the assumptions you see in my answer above, or the weaker assumptions used in the Gauss–Markov theorem, my answer remains intact: one is estimating $(\theta_0,\theta_1). \qquad$

Comment: Thanks for your patience, Michael. My only concern is that $\Theta$ should parametrize the family of probability measures.  Whereas under the weaker assumptions ($Y_i$ not independent or normal), the expectations of the $Y_i$ do not determine the probability measure $(Y_1,...,Y_n)_\ast(\nu)$.

Comment: That is we may have $(Y_1,...,Y_n)_\ast(\nu) \neq (Y'_1,...,Y'_n)_\ast(\nu)$ but $E(Y_i)=E(Y_i')$. $(Y_1,...,Y_n)_\ast(\nu)$ and $\neq (Y'_1,...,Y'_n)_\ast(\nu)$ are members of our family of probability measures on $\Omega$, but they aren't distinguished by anything (like the $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ in your example) that depends only on the expectations of the $Y_i$.

Comment: @Timkinsella : There is such a thing as estimation of quantities of interest that do not parametrize probability distributions. Under the hypotheses of the Gauss–Markov theorem, the values of what may be sometimes referred to as "parameters" do not completely determine just one probability measure, but certainly one is estimating them by using least squares.